# Retrieve the JSON Object

Tags: java, json

Below I have attached Java code, In that first i am retrieving the "images" result as "**{"jpg":"JPEG file","gif":"GIF file","png":"PNG File"}**"

using the resultant, trying to get the "jpg" node, not able to retrieve the data, instead i am getting error as `java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject`

I like to take the images and followed by jpg. not directly JPG value

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

    public class JSONDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try{
            String jsonfile="{ \"name\" : \"Raj\", \"Address\" : \"Chennai\", \"images\": { \"jpg\" : \"JPEG file\", \"png\" : \"PNG File\", \"gif\" : \"GIF file\" }}";
            JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject();
            JSONParser jparser=new JSONParser();
            jobject = (JSONObject) jparser.parse(jsonfile);
            jobject=(JSONObject) jobject.get("images");
            System.out.println(jobject);
            System.out.println(jobject.getClass().getName());

            jobject=(JSONObject) jobject.get("jpg");
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error here is that "jpg" is not a `JSONObject`, but a key with the associated value `"JPEG file"` which is a simple String. That is why you're getting such error.

In ordre to retrieve the value associated to the key `jpg`, read the below code. I added some comments to help you understand each steps, but feel free to ask for more details.

```
    String jsonfile="{ \"name\" : \"Raj\", \"Address\" : \"Chennai\", \"images\": { \"jpg\" : \"JPEG file\", \"png\" : \"PNG File\", \"gif\" : \"GIF file\" }}";

    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject();
    JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();

    //Convert your string jsonfile into a JSONObject   
    try {
        jobject = (JSONObject) jparser.parse(jsonfile);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Josimarleewords.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println(jobject.toString());    
    //{"Address":"Chennai","name":"Raj","images":{"jpg":"JPEG file","png":"PNG File","gif":"GIF file"}}

    //Get the node image, and convert it into a JSONObject
    //You're able to do so, because the value associated to "images"
    //is in json format.
    jobject=(JSONObject) jobject.get("images");
    System.out.println(jobject.toString()); 
    //{"jpg":"JPEG file","png":"PNG File","gif":"GIF file"}

    //Retrieves the value associated to the key jpg.
    //The value here is not in json format, it is a simple string
    String jpg = (String)jobject.get("jpg");                 
    System.out.println(jpg.toString());
    //JPEG file
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as solved by validating the answer.

Comment: On the left of my answer, below the upvote/downvote buttons, there is a validate button.